# How to select rows from mySQL table and merge together (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hi I am trying to create a shopping site for a project. I have a table in a database that contains the items. I have managed to read from the table. Alongside each row I have added a checkbox. I want the user to select one or more item and press the submit button. When they do this, the details of the order should merge and get added to another table. How can I do this?

Here is the code to display the items. Each row in the table contains a checkbox. There is also a submit button.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Shopping</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action='buy.php' method='post'>
<input type='submit' value='Submit' />
</form> 
<h1>Buy</h1>
<?php // Script 12.7 - shopping.php

$db = mysql_connect('localhost', '#####', '#####');
mysql_select_db('shopping', $db);

$query = 'SELECT * FROM Items';

if ($r = mysql_query($query, $db)) { 
    print "<table>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r)) {
        print 
        "<tr>
        <td>{$row['ID']}</td>
        <td>{$row['Name']}</td>
        <td>{$row['Cost']}</td>
        <td><input type='checkbox' name='buy' value='buy' /></td>
        </tr>";
    }
    print "</table>";

} else { 
    print '<p style="color: blue">Error!</p>';
} 

mysql_close($db); // Close the connection.

?>
</body>
</html>
```

The page it navigates to (buy.php) is currently empty and thats wat I need help on. I want the details of the order to be entered into the following table:

```
Table name: order_details
fields: ID, Items, Total_Cost
```

I want the ID to obviously be a random number. I want the items column to merge the ID's of the items. Finally, I want the Total_cost column to display the sum of all the selected items.

Answer (score 0):

Your checkboxes with name and value set to 'buy' are a bad start. There is no way of identifying the checked item in the script that processes this form. The name should be changed to `name='buy[{$row['ID']}]'` so you can retrieve the ids of the selected items. Your form should wrap around all the checkboxes (the whole table).

Your order_details table is a perfect example of how not to do it. Multi-value fields are evil for all sorts of reasons. In a typical order structure you might have `orders(id, user_id, created, status)` and `order_items(id, order_id, item_id, quantity, unit_price)`. This is a slightly naive but usable structure. Total order value can easily be calculated on the fly based on the quantities and unit_prices.

You need to make an attempt at a solution and then ask specific questions instead of asking us to write the whole solution for you. A quick search on Google for "php mysql shopping cart tutorial" returns lots of tutorials on this topic.